# How to run a Blender API script using a subprocess?

Tags: python, blender

I am planning a simple script, that outputs a value of an X-coordinate of a cube to a console on an infinite loop. As user moves the cube around, the output is updated.

e.g.:

```
while True:
      print(<Cube.001 x-coordinate>)
```

However, Blender hangs during the infinite loop, as it is busy running the script to run the GUI. I've read that python's subsystem might be a solution, but havent seen any examples so far.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.